# Create directory structure using template in a text file

Tags: r, directory, stringr

Suppose I have a text file `text.txt` that contains several lines of text indented using single spaces (not tabs) like:

```
My folder1/
  My folder2/ 
  My folder3/ 
     file1.md
My folder4/
```

For example, and actual directory template might look like:

```
Proposal/
 rules/
 proposal/
  document.tex
  figs/
  tabs/
  ref/
  log/
  src/
   master.r
   crdat/
   andat/
  temp/
  data/
   raw/
   clean/

Admin/
  budget/
  contract/
  invoices/
  receipts/
  team/
   hiring/
   vitae/
  gantt/  
  forms/
  misc/

Study/
 document.tex
 figs/
 tabs/
 ref/
 log/
 src/
  master.r
  crdat/
  andat/
 temp/
 data/
  raw/
  clean/

Dissemination/
 presentations/
  conference1/
   submission.md
   slides.tex
   notes.md
   admin/
    registration/
    travel/
    receipts/
    program/
    forms/
  conference2/
 manuscripts/
  journal1/
   submission/
    letter_v1.tex
    manuscript_v1.pdf
    replication_v1.zip
    comments/
     reviewer1.txt
   R&R/
    letter_v2.tex
    manuscript_v2.tex
    diff.tex
    replication_v2.zip
  journal2/

master_notes.md
TODOs.md
README.md
```

Essentially the file is a template for directory structure.  This template can be set by the user.  She could use different templates for different projects say, and the names are generic.  The only constraints are that hierarchy is established using spaces, and folders end in forward slash.

I want to write a function that takes a any such directory template as an input and creates a directory structure in your current working directory.  The pseudo code is as follows:

```
lines <- readLines(text.txt)
last.indent <- 0
for (i in lines) {
  Create directory structure by looking at leading character and last characters (folders end in /)
  using dir.create(i) or file.create(i)
}
```

Comment: After your edits this will take a little more time than I thought.  I'll look at it in about 10 hours

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're actually doing something more complicated.  In which case this may not work:

```
library(qdap); library(reports)

x <- readLines(n=13) ## you'd read this in from a file I assume
My folder1/
  My folder2/ 
  My folder3/ 
     file1.md
My folder4/
My folder1b/
  My folder2/ 
  My folder3/ 
     file1.zip
My folder1c/
  My folder2/ 
  My folder3/ 
     file1.pdf

## You didn't ask for this but this keeps the direcories contained
new <- folder(new)
setwd(new)

dirs <- which(substring(x, 1, 1) != " ")

lens <- lapply(seq_along(dirs), function(i) {
    dirs[i]:c(tail(dirs - 1, -1), length(x))[i]
})

paths <- split(x, rep(1:length(dirs), sapply(lens, length)))

path <- sapply(paths, function(x) paste(Trim(x), collapse=""))
is.dir <- sapply(path, function(x) substring(x, nchar(x))) == "/"

lapply(seq_along(is.dir), function(i){
     out <- folder(folder.name =ifelse(is.dir[i], 
         path[i], dirname(path[i])))
     if(!is.dir[i]) {
         cat("", file = paste0(path[i], "_hold_.txt"))
     }
})
```

Comment: The names `My Folder1/` are meant to be generic.  They could be `project/` say.  The only thing that distinguishes a folder from a file si not structure of name by forward slash at end.

Comment: Rstudio crashes when I try to run your code.  Note I am using a different template and some of the files are called letter_v1.tex  manuscript_v1.pdf replication_v1.zip even though they exist only in name.

Comment: If they only exist in name what's the point of putting them in there?  I mean are they place holders?  Maybe you should explain what you're trying to do in more detail.

Comment: I am trying to create a directory structure for a generic project.  Putting place holders gives an indication of what should go where.  6 months from now when I use this to create a new project I might not remember.

Comment: Gotcha.  I think then you could solve this by adding a .txt to the files to prevent an attempt to create zip and pdf files.  I'll throw it into the code above.

Comment: When I run your code on the example directory template above RStudio crashes each and every time.  It bombs on the last line as i execute it line by line.

Comment: You'd have to provide `sessionInfo` as I run in RStudio and get no such error.